# Is it possible to have a virtual type in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, module

I have a class `MyClass` (with several virtual functions) that performs operations on an object called `MyType`.

The class `MyClassImpl` inherits `MyClass` and implements the virtual functions, but I need to add additional members to `MyType`, but I don't want to modify the class `MyType` (instead I want to keep it generic).

Now, if I make a `MyTypeImpl` and inherit `MyType`, I can add members. But, how do I make the non virtual functions in `MyClassImpl` (inherited from `MyClass`) use the new `MyTypeImpl`?

The only way I can think is to make `MyClass` use `MyTypeImpl` but I want to avoid using the implementation in the generic class because I might use various different implementations.

Here is a simple example of what the classes might look like. Of course, the code will not compile because the methods and members added in `MyTypeImpl` and not `MyType`.

```cpp
class MyType {
  public:
    void increment() {
      data_++;
    }
  protected:
    int data_ = 0;
};

class MyClass {
  public:   
    void alg() {
      sub_routine_1();
      sub_routine_2();
      modify_mytype();
    };

  protected:
    MyType mytype_;

    virtual void sub_routine_1() = 0;
    virtual void sub_routine_2() = 0;

    void modify_mytype() {
      mytype_.increment();
    };
};

class MyTypeImpl : public MyType {
  public:
    void decrement() {
      data_--;
      is_decremented = true;
    };

  protected:
    bool is_decremented = false;;
};

class MyClassImpl : public MyClass{
  public:
    void print() {
      mytype_.print();
    };
  protected:
    virtual void sub_routine_1() {
      //do algorithm things here
      mytype_.increment();
      mytype_.increment();
    };
    virtual void sub_routine_2() {
      //do more algorithm things here
      mytype_.decrement();
      mytype_.decrement();
    };
};
```

Comment: Could you provide a use case, or an example of some code that you've written that tries to accomplish this? I think that'd help to make your question clearer

Comment: if you cannot/do not want to provide a general interface at the level of MyType (e.g. in form of a pure or empty implemented virtual function), then you'll have to test and/or dynamically cast to MyTypeImpl ind MyClassImpl.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59742156/edit) and add a code example of what you're trying to do? Even if you can't do it exactly, a concrete example will help us understand you better.

Comment: It sounds like you want something [visitor-ish.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: I will make up a simple example and add to description.

Comment: You can make `MyClass` use a pointer to the base class `MyType` and use polymorphism to resolve to the correct derived `MyTypeImpl` class functions. I tried to write up an example that uses all the same wording you used above.

Comment: Yes polymorphism is what you want. You will need to make `MyClass` hold a pointer to `MyType`, then you can assign any derived `MyTypeImpl` object to that pointer and polymorphically call the correct implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing your example I see now that you just want to extend the functionality of that class without modifying the original class. If you need to add additional functions, but you don't want to change the type that is stored in `MyClass` there isn't any way I know of to make that happen without at least modifying `MyType` to include virtual functions for the functions you want to call.

You also need to make `MyClass` take a pointer to `MyType` so you can use polymorphism and make the calls resolve to the correct implementation:

## Dynamic Polymorphism Solution:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyType {
  public:
    virtual void increment() {
      data_++;
    }

    // To be implemented by implementation class
    virtual void print() = 0;

    // To be implemented by implementation class
    virtual void decrement() = 0;

  protected:
    int data_ = 0;
};

class MyTypeImpl : public MyType
{
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << 42 << std::endl;
    }

    void decrement() {
        data_--;
        is_decremented = true;
    };

protected:
    bool is_decremented = false;;
};

class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass(MyType* mytype)
        : mytype_(mytype)
    {}

    void alg() {
      sub_routine_1();
      sub_routine_2();
      modify_mytype();
    };

  protected:
    MyType* mytype_;

    virtual void sub_routine_1() = 0;
    virtual void sub_routine_2() = 0;

    void modify_mytype() {
      mytype_->increment();
    };
};

class MyClassImpl : public MyClass{
  public:
    MyClassImpl(MyType* mytype)
        : MyClass(mytype)
    {}

    void print() {
      mytype_->print();
    };
  protected:
    virtual void sub_routine_1() {
      //do algorithm things here
      mytype_->increment();
      mytype_->increment();
    };
    virtual void sub_routine_2() {
      //do more algorithm things here
      mytype_->decrement();
      mytype_->decrement();
    };
};

int main()
{
    MyType* mytype = new MyTypeImpl();
    MyClass* myclass = new MyClassImpl(mytype);

    // Prints "42"
    myclass->print();

    // Do other stuff with "myclass"

    delete myclass;
    delete mytype;
}
```

> Note, I am only using a raw pointer in this example for increased clarity. It is highly recommended that you don't use `new` and `delete` and use smart pointers to manage the lifetime of your pointers instead.

## Static Polymorphism Solution:

Not that the design of this solution is actually any better, but I think this is closer to what you are actually looking for because it doesn't require modifying the `MyType` class directly. Also the only modification needed for `MyClass` is to make it a template class:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyType {
  public:
    virtual void increment() {
      data_++;
    }

  protected:
    int data_ = 0;
};

class MyTypeImpl : public MyType
{
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << data_ << std::endl;
    }

    void decrement() {
        data_--;
        is_decremented = true;
    };

protected:
    bool is_decremented = false;
};

template <typename T>
class MyClass {
  public:

    void alg() {
      sub_routine_1();
      sub_routine_2();
      modify_mytype();
    };

  protected:
    T mytype_;

    virtual void sub_routine_1() = 0;
    virtual void sub_routine_2() = 0;

    void modify_mytype() {
      mytype_.increment();
    };
};

template <typename T>
class MyClassImpl : public MyClass<T> {
  public:
    void print() {
      this->mytype_.print();
    };

  protected:
    virtual void sub_routine_1() {
      //do algorithm things here
        this->mytype_.increment();
        this->mytype_.increment();
    };
    virtual void sub_routine_2() {
      //do more algorithm things here
        this->mytype_.decrement();
        this->mytype_.decrement();
    };
};

int main()
{
    // Use the template to get the correct implementation
    MyClassImpl<MyTypeImpl> myclass;

    myclass.alg();
    myclass.print();

    // Do other stuff with my class
}
```

Comment: This might be the only solution, but I want to avoid modifying MyType and MyClass (or at least avoiding adding anything related to potential implementations). MyClass and MyType do something very specific, and I want to expand that functionality by adding members and methods (only in child classes). This could be done simply if MyClass didn't operate on MyType, but if I add a member in the MyType child class, MyClass won't see it.

Comment: You don't need to add the implementation details to `MyType` directly, but if you want to add new functions to `MyTypeImpl` that are accessible through the interface of `MyType` you would still need to add them to the interface of `MyType` otherwise you have no way of calling them. Basically `MyType` acts as a consistent interface to multiple implementations. You can provide multiple `MyTypeImpl`, `MyTypeImpl2`, etc... implementation classes that can be accessed through the `MyType` interface.

Comment: Alternatively you could look into using templates for a "static" polymorphism solution. Although I'm not sure that will get you much closer to what you want. I'll see if I can write up an example of that.

Comment: I've updated the solution with a static polymorphism solution that uses templates. Hopefully this is closer to what you are looking for since it doesn't require modification of the `MyType` class directly.

Comment: I know the structure is weird, but I think is appropriate for my application. While some drawbacks exist using a template (e.g., only children of MyType actually valid but are not enforced), but this is indeed what I was looking for. Thanks for the help. I am not sure why I didn't think of using a template :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) Hopefully C++20 will provide a better solution to problems like this with "concepts". I'm not fully familiar with how they work yet but I think that might actually be the best solution to this problem.